# how to read a value during installation of android application

Tags: android

1. Hey friends,i am doing one android application:
          -in that i want to read value from the users during an installation of application.
2. if any code for that please share a code and steps
   Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> in that i want to read value from the users during an installation of application.

This is not possible. Your app will not run at all until the user runs it from the home screen's launcher. At that point, you are welcome to prompt the user to supply you with information.